# Regular, connected, bipartite graph with no Hamilton cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonicity

Find an example of a graph $G$ with 3 or more vertices that is regular, connected, bipartite, and contains no Hamilton cycle. Please give me a *hint*.

What I've got so far: Since $G$ is regular and bipartite, its two sets of vertices are of equal sizes. $G$ is probably $3$-regular because the more edges there are, the harder it is to avoid having a Hamilton cycle, but this isn't strictly necessary. I know I am supposed to construct $G $ so that the subgraph test for Hamilton cycle shows that $G$ doesn't have a Hamilton cycle.

Comment: Try to find a graph with 3 vertices in each side, with Hamilton path, but not a Hamilton cycle

Comment: @Shaq I don't think that works. If we have 3 vertices on each side then we get $K_{3,3}$ because $G$ has to be regular.

Comment: You are right, my bad

Comment: I tried to play with it a bit.. Are you sure it is possible? I don't have a  proof you cannot construct one, but are you sure there is not?

Comment: I am not sure at all. My textbook asks me to find such a graph, so there ought to be one.

Comment: An  idea I have - in 2-regular of course it won't work, because the graph itself is a Hamilton cycle. Now a proof you cannot construct such a graph could be - if the graph is n-regular, we can take off edges so it remains a 2-regular, and this is a Hamilton cycle in the original graph. So we can start with try to construct 3-regular(or more than 3) graph that do not have a 2-regular subgraph

Comment: @Shaq Every bipartite regular graph has a perfect matching, and therefore has a 2-regular subgraph (by taking 2 perfect matchings) but your argument doesn't work, because the 2-regular subgraph need not be connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by the "subgraph test for Hamiltonian cycle" you mean the toughness test: if there is a way to delete $k>0$ vertices from the graph and leave more than $k$ connected components, then the graph is not Hamiltonian.

The smallest $k$ that works is $k=2$; $k=1$ runs into trouble with vertex degrees in the components. For example, there is a $3$-regular connected bipartite graph $G$ with two vertices $\{v,w\}$ such that $G - \{v,w\}$ has three components. This is necessarily not Hamiltonian.

(A good approach to see if there is a graph satisfying some conditions is to look it up on the [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/). You can search for all graphs with the conditions `Bipartite = true AND Regular = true AND Connected = true AND Hamiltonian = false`, and it will find you some examples.)

Comment: I didn't know it was called 'the toughness test'. Shouldn't there be a 'clever' way to find an example?

Comment: It has that name because a graph is called "tough" if deleting $k>0$ vertices leaves at most $k$ components, for any $k$. All Hamiltonian graphs are tough, though not all tough graphs are Hamiltonian, unfortunately.

Comment: As far as "clever ways" to find an example: with the conditions that $G-\{v,w\}$ has three components, and the idea that these components ought to be symmetric-looking and not too large, you should be able to arrive at an example after some experimentation. Once you've seen this type of construction, you'll start recognizing it in other counterexamples (e.g. [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sylvester_counter.svg) showing that not all cubic graphs have a perfect matching).

Comment: Is one born with this kind of intuition? Or is it gained from experience?

Comment: I think it's mostly gained from the habit of seeing proof techniques and checking if they can be applied to other things. (The more techniques you see, the better this habit will work.)